# get the maximum Set size from a HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, set, java-stream

I have a hashMap of `<Integer, Set<Integer>>.`

I'm willing to get the Set that have the maximum size using java stream operation.

Here is my example:

```
public class Example {

     public static void main( String[] args ) {
         Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();
         Set<Integer> set1 = Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         Set<Integer> set2 = Stream.of(1,2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         adj.put(1,set1);
         adj.put(2,set2);
     }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
 Collections.max(adj,Comparator.comparingInt(Set::size));
```

but I'm getting a compilation error because the size() method in the Set interface is not static.

Normally we should get 3 as the maximum size set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>>` with `Collection.max`. as it's defined as taking a Collection.

```
public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)
```

So, to make it work, either do:

```
Collections.max(adj.values(), Comparator.comparingInt(Set::size));
```

or a stream:

```
adj.values()
   .stream()
   .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Set::size));
```

Answer (score 3):

> we should get 3 as the maximum size set.

To get the maximum size of a `Set` within the map you can use:

```
int maxSetSize = adj.values()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Set::size))
        .map(Set::size)
        .orElse(0);
```

Comment: or `… .mapToInt(Set::size).max() …`